# Is it possible to cut parts out of a picture and analyze them separately with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I am doing some studies on eye vascularization - my project contains a machine which can detect the different blood vessels in the retinal membrane at the back of the eye. What I am looking for is a possibility to segment the picture and analyze each segmentation on its own. The Segmentation consists of six squares which I want to analyze separately on the density of white pixels.

I would be very thankful for every kind of input, I am pretty new in the programming world an I actually just have a bare concept on how it should work.

Thanks and Cheerio

[Concept Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKf00.jpg)
[OCTA PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BTZa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably accomplish this by using numpy to load the image and split it into sections.  You could then analyze the sections using [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org) or [opencv](http://opencv.org) (though this could be difficult to get working.  To view the image, you can either save it to a file using numpy, or use matplotlib to open it in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that in image processing "segmentation" describes the process of grouping neighbouring pixels by context.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation

What you want to do can be done in various ways.

The most common way is by using ROIs or AOIs (region/area of interest). That's basically some geometric shape like a rectangle, circle, polygon or similar defined in image coordinates.
The image processing is then restricted to only process pixels within that region. So you don't slice your image into pieces but you restrict your evaluation to specific areas.

Another way, like you suggested is to cut the image into pieces and process them one by one. Those sub-images are usually created using ROIs.

A third option which is rather limited but sufficient for simple tasks like yours is accessing pixels directly using coordinate offsets and several nested loops.

Just google "python image processing" in combination with "library" "roi" "cropping" "sliding window" "subimage" "tiles" "slicing" and you'll get tons of information...

Comment: Thank you, I`m going to read me in this ROI topic, I think that is a very useful hint. Because I was struggling to cut it into pieces. My major problem is that the size of each eye differs from each other and the subsections need to be applied manually. The sensor of this machine can only take 2.9 mm x 2.9mm if you have a different size of the eye-nerve and you need to analyze the squares around it you need to adjust it for each,... is this even possible?

Comment: @SaMi absolutely.